# I am trying to print out user input to find the max amount of apples I can get in the boxes but can't get the boxes to print correctly

Tags: c++

My code at the moment prints out the max amount of apples but not the correct boxes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int apples[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> apples[i];
    int max_including = apples[0];
    int max_excluding = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        int temp = max(max_including, max_excluding);
        max_including = max_excluding + apples[i];
        max_excluding = temp;
    }

    cout << "Boxes:";
    cout << apples[0] << " ";
    for (i = 0; n < i; i++)
    {
        if (apples[i] > 0)
        {
            cout << apples[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    int ans = max(max_including, max_excluding);
    cout << "\nMax Apples:" << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

I have one constraint to where if a box is used, I must skip at least the next box.
Some samples of what I should get are:
Input

```
4
3
2
3
5
```

The output should return

```
Boxes:0 3
Max Apples:8
```

However I can only get mine to return

```
Boxes:3
Max Apples:8
```

Another sample is:
Input

```
1
500
```

The output should return

```
Boxes:0
Max Apples:500
```

However I can only get mine to return

```
Boxes:500
Max Apples:500
```

How would I fix this code to properly output the correct corresponding boxes? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain why the given input should return the output you've shown?

Comment: The first number in the input is how many boxes there are. So for instance: 4 would be the initial box count, 3 apples are in box 0, 2 apples are in box 1, 3 apples are in box 2, and 5 apples are in box 3. Hence the max amount of apples are in boxes 0 and 3 because I have to skip at least the next box if a box is used. Same with the other example: 1 is the initial amount of boxes and 500 apples are in box 0. Hence box 0 is the max as it is the only one.

Comment: `for (i = 0; n < i; i++)` doesn't look right at all.

Comment: Any suggestions of how to fix it Beta?

Comment: `i < n` would at least let the loop run.